# Anyone get ruby-tk to install on El Capitan?

Tags: ruby, macos, tk-toolkit

Anyone get ruby-tk to install on El Capitan? The tk bindings do not seem to come included. Been trying for a while to get any ruby-tk up and running with no love, including compiling from source (errors!) and homebrew (no tk!)

Thanks in advance,
Craig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ruby tcl/tk installation guide for mac os x el capitan

1. install brew (follow the brew installation guide)
   http://brew.sh/
2. install http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads
3. press option+click to install the ActiveTcl 8.5 dmg file.
4. install rvm (follow the rvm installation guide)
   https://rvm.io/rvm/install
5. install ruby with tcl and tk: 
   rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.3 --with-tcl --with-tk
6. use the newly download ruby version: 
   rvm use 2.2.3 --default

[installation reference](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/16sp/ruby.pdf)
[download link](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads)
[guides/tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com//ruby/ruby_tk_guide.htm)

Answer (score 1):

On MacOSX Catalina

Warning (Only do this for old legacy projects use a different GUI for new projects)

Tk is dependant on Ruby gems

[Install brew](http://brew.sh/)

```
brew install libgd
brew install tcl-tk
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
sudo gem install tk
```

- Install perlbrew
- Install cpan
- Install cpan branch

perlbrew switch 5.14.4

Download and install XQuartz dmg
https://www.xquartz.org/

try without force first!

```
perlbrew switch 5.14.4
cpanm install Try::Tiny
cpanm install YAML
cpanm install GD::Simple
cpanm install GD::Graph
cpanm install Tk
```

Answer (score 0):

Got ruby-tk to work by installing rvm and ruby-head, instructions [here](https://www.computersnyou.com/5307/setup-homebrew-and-rvm-on-mac-osx-10-11-ei-capitan/) No other installs/configuration was necessary to run my ruby-tk scripts other than the recipe on that page. Thanks, Alok Yadav!